# JSON not loading in IE7 & 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

My JSON content loads in all browsers except IE7 & 8, I'm not sure why it isn't working, the following is the code, any ideas? Thanks!

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

function loadContent(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            showStartpage(data);
            showInfo(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to load content");
        }
    }); 

}

function showStartpage(){
        $(".start .text3").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text3']);
        $(".start .text4").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text4']);
        $(".start .text5").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text5']);
        $(".start .text6").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text6']);
        $(".start .text7").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text7']);
}

loadContent();
showStartpage();

}
```

Comment: Press F-12 to open the debugger, the look at CONSOLE to see any errors. "Not working" doesn't help in troubleshooting much.

Comment: No F-12 in IE7 though.

Comment: You don't need to include `data: "nocache=" + Math.random()` if you set `cache: false` instead.

Comment: It seems in IE when I call this function it gives me an error setDayDelay();, it says "Object doesn't support this property or method message with function call"

Comment: For JSON to work in older IE you need to call the json js

Comment: there was an error in my function, didn't set a variable as global. sorry for wasting time :(

Answer (score 0):

try including `json.js` in your code, it might me helpful.

download it from [**here**](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), include `json2.js`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the following ajax setup in order for it to work correctly:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Adding this solved the problem for me.